# Backend POST error: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js

I'm developing a MERN app with MySQL.
My app is about a simple blogs, people post things.

I've connected backend (tested and works perfectly) and frontend using **React** with axios (works correctly).
When i make a `POST` request from the frontend, it works, adds the object to **MySQL database**, but when a i do a `POST` req again, `CMD` gives me the following error:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client,

Then it ends the localhost server connection until i modify the backend code.

React frontend forms code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { createBlogRequest } from "../api/blosg.api";

function Poster() {
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState("");
  const [newPost, setNewPost] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(targeted)
    try {
      const response = await createBlogRequest(targeted)
      console.log(response)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
  const targeted = {name: newUser, post: newPost}

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="user"
        placeholder="escribi tu nombre..."
        onChange={(e) => setNewUser(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <textarea
        name="post"
        cols="30"
        rows="10"
        placeholder="escribi algo dale..."
        onChange={(e) => setNewPost(e.target.value)}
      ></textarea>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Subir</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Poster;
```

the createBlog controller backend:

```
export const createBlog = async(req, res) => {
    const {name, post} = req.body
    const [result] = await pool.query('INSERT INTO blogs (name, post) VALUES (?, ?)',[
        name, post
    ])
    res.json({
        id: result.insertId, name, post,
    })
    console.log(result)
    return res.send('creando blogs')
}
```

the routes backend

```
router.post('/blogs', createBlog)
```

the axios connection:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const createBlogRequest = async (blog) =>{
    await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/blogs', blog)
}
```

I've used the CORS module, to give access, etc.
Any response will be received

Comment: In backend controller, calling `res.json` already sets the `content-type` headers and the body of the response. Calling `res.send` again attempts to set the `content-type` header, hence the error. You should send the response only once.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP response headers are sent in both `res.json` and `res.send`. The headers can only be sent one time. The `res.write` should be used if multiple responses have to be sent - usually due to the processing of data in intervals. See the [Anatomy of HTTP](https://rapidapi.com/comics/the-anatomy-of-http-requests).

The correct response in the current scenario should be a composite one. Something like this:

```
   res.json({
    id: result.insertId, 
    name, 
    post,
    message: 'creando blogs' 
})
```

Comment: Sorry for late comment, thanks, it works!